# unexpected token error in bash script

Tags: bash

I am getting an error in line 8: unexpected token then

```
#!/bash/bin/bash
echo -e "enter the filename: \c"
read file_content
if [ -f $file_content ]
then

if [ -w $file_content ]
then
echo "Please Press Ctrl+d to exit"
echo cat >> $file_content
else "You dont have permission to write"
fi
else
echo " You have file name $file_content"
fi
```

Comment: The code looks fine, however at line 11 I believe echo is missing and at line 1 path is also incorrect. It must be like `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: What is this script supposed to do? The command `echo cat >> $file_content` will append the string `cat` into the file `$file_content`. Is that what you want?

Comment: All i am trying to append output to the end of text file. This is code that i worte

Answer (score 2):

Your script should look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "enter the filename: \c"
something_to_add=/path/to/something_to_add/file
read -r file_content
if [ -f "$file_content" ]
then    
        if [ -w "$file_content" ]
        then
                echo "Please Press Ctrl+c to exit"
                cat "$something_to_add" >> "$file_content"
        else 
                echo "You dont have permission to write"
        fi
else
        echo "You have file name $file_content"
fi
```

Errors noted:

1. Shebang: wrong (`#!/bash/bin/bash`) right (`#!/bin/bash`), better (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`).
2. Inner `if` statement has a wrong `else` segment.
3. Added double quotes where necessary.
4. Rather than `echo cat >>` do `cat >>`

Use this online service to check your script:

https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @susan It seems to me that what the OP had in mind is a script which allows the user to append some input to the file, so it should rather be `cat >> "$file_content"`, without the echo. But that's not a critique on your answer as the question was just about the syntax.

Comment: Yes that would be the case!

Comment: This student homework project still isn't complete. For example `Press ctrl+D to exit` isn't working. Also `cat` needs a filename to process. Which is probably `$file_content` in this case the other side of `>>` should be something like `$all_files_content`. The second last line should read `echo "Filename: $file_content does not exist."`. The student should mention this for version 2.0 of your script... +1 :)

Comment: A strange planet we live on @wineunuuchs2unix :-).

Comment: All i am trying  to append output to the end of text file. This is code that i worte